# what happens when we do go one page forward and one page back in browser does it hit the server and reload the page?

Tags: asp.net

In my code i am maintaining some session on page load and some button click.
It works fine
but in browser if do Go back one page or go forward one page it disturb all session.

So what is the concept behind Go back one page, go forward one page in browser.

When we go forward or go back, does page reload from the server.

Comment: `it disturb all session` ... What does happen actually? Do you get any error or the page doesn't gets loaded?

Comment: no dont get error, but it maintains the previous seesion and when i move back from the browser button "forward a page back" and then on the page if i click the a button that is to perform something, but when i click it, on page load it sees the previous session and act according to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends by your configuration.

You can add the below code to your master page to force the reload for all the pages

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```